# Can Google Chrome show separate taskbar icons for applications

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, taskbar

I use applications in google chrome a lot, so gmail, hootsuite etc all have their own application. I find it fits well with how I like to work. So if I want gmail I tap the windows key type gmail and tap enter. Done.

What I'd like to see is each chrome application with its own icon in the task bar. Windows 7 groups them all together making it harder to find applications in the task bar.

Is there a way that I can have separate icons in the task bar for chrome applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to create desktop links/shortcuts to each of the applications, then drag them  to your Windows 7 Taskbar to pin them there.

That way Windows will always have them there and will never group them together. It works in theory and won't affect how your other programs are displayed! :D

Comment: It looks like this no longer works in Windows 10.

Answer (score 5):

- Right-click on an empty space on your taskbar
- Select **Properties**
- Select the *Taskbar* tab of the *Taskbar and Start Menu* dialog that pops up
- Select **Never combine** on Taskbar buttons
- Click **OK** to save.

Now, when you break out each of the Google Chrome tabs, they will split up and show their own taskbar icons.

Currently this will affect other programs and how they group on the taskbart and can't be done on a per application/program basis.

Comment: This sucks quite a lot because you have to show the label too. Wont make my taskbar this ugly just to have an extra icon

Answer (score 2):

On Windows 10: 
Create Shortcut to Chrome where

```
target="C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app="https://yorusite.com"
```

[image: 1]
`--app`: This will force chrome to open the window in "application" mode.  The chrome instance will not be combined with other chrome instances in the taskbar and the icon in the taskbar will match that of the site.

Example:

```
Target="C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app="https://admin.microsoft.com/adminportal#/homepage"
```

Comment: This did not work for me (maybe deprecated as of Nov 2022) but this knowledge article was amazing and does exactly what is wanted here, at least as far as opening individual sites as a separate instance with the favicon as the taskbar icon in Windows 10. :)
https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/3060053?hl=en

Comment: @Slink That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks!! You should add an actual answer.